# Code First Migration Entity Framework 6 Empty Up/Down

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

The problem I'm having is that when I "Add-Migration", it seems that no comparison against the target database is done and the Up/Down methods are empty.

This starts from me targeting different environments.  The migration changes work fine when I update-database and it targets one particular database, my dev database.

When I change the connection string to target another database, another dev box on another server, and try to add-migration for that particular environment, the Up/Down methods are always empty.

I tried targeting an update-database to roll back changes to a previous migration at the 2nd dev box but it didn't change anything.

Is there anything that I need to specifically do if I'm migrating code-first changes from one environment to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a new migration, you need to force EF to run all the old ones. Try specifying the source and target migrations:

```
Update-Database -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: AddPostAbstract
```

Another option would be to generate a script that you can run against the other database by adding -Script to the command.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script

If you have a lot of migrations you could role them up by deleting them and doing a fresh add-migration.

Comment: I think I realized what happened.  It seems that someone was making changes to the database directly and then using the vs2013 add ado.net entity model, to recreate the code first entities and structure.  So essentially, the in-between migrations did not exist.  I think this is what was screwing up with the comparison models of the database.

What this amounts to , is there a way to create a migration in such a way that a full comparison is done between the target database and the current code first model without usage of migration documents?

Comment: You could do a fresh initial migration. You will get Up() and Down() code for everything and you could comment out the existing stuff.. The other option is to just do a schema compare between the 2 databases. http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Yeah, that's actually exactly what I did.  I generated a fresh initial migration and then did a comparison of the schema on the two severs and then commented out the similarities on the code. It was a pain in the behind but it worked and I learned something.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this empty up() and down() showing up at every attempt for hours. Tried even starting over a new project .. didn't work ..

Until I've had the idea of setting up, in visual studio, the data project as the default startup project of the solution .. then magic happened!

Can't really say if it's a solution (because I still don't see the connection to the base problem) but may be it could help somebody which visual studio's cosmic sign is the same as mine :)

Comment: So, if you are using Visual Studio, one thing that I noticed was that the migration uses the connection strings defined in the startup project to run it's comparison and migration.  When you changed the startup project to your data project, it started using the configurations defined in that project.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was generating an initial migration and then compared the schema between the two servers (@Steve Greene commented with a great link describing what I did to do the comparison here: http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/).  I then, painstakingly, walked through the migration code and commented out what was unnecessary.

Once the migration ran successfully, everything went back to running smoothly.

I'm not sure if there is a better way of handling it, but this worked for me.