# Application to compare database schema and data

Tags: c#, sql-server, compare, schema, dac

I am trying to do a simple windows forms app to compare two databases and commit changes or printout the update script. For this I found that the  Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx might help. However, after installing the framework, the DAC.compare is no longer available. as you can see in the following link: [missing DAC Compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltk2g.png)

Can anyone help? some example would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the [Nuget package for DacFx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/)? My guess would be that you need to make your app specifically target x86 to be able to use it. Admittedly [the according info on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn702988.aspx) is very thin.

Comment: is there another option? SSDT, I am also looking at this option. The objective is to compare schema, data if needed, commit changes with or without exceptions, in the end generate a compare script. Incredibly, there is not a lot of  info out there.

Comment: My bet on the most up-to-date implementation would be Entity Framework if you want to include it in your own app. If you just need a tool, SSDT is the way to go: It allows you to create a database project that comes with the option to compare instances of your database and creating the script to sync their schema.

Comment: I want to create an app, where it can do this comparison and update, if you know of any examples, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @User10321649 There is a tool by redgate which does this: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index Building one yourself will be quite an undertaking as there are a lot of different variations and scenarios and I doubt you will find an example program to study since people who created these tools will want to sell them after the investment of effort... To get started you can have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987701/comparing-two-sql-server-database-schema-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you Milney for your input. Nevertheless, I would like to take the challenge :). currently studying the tool sqlcompare.exe (free) also looking at the ssdt, but very limited information on them.

Comment: This is the namespace I am looking for which is not available in the DAC.extensions anymore. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.compare.schemacomparedacpacendpoint.schemacomparedacpacendpoint.aspx

Comment: I tried the linked Nuget package and found out that apart from the x86 dependency, it also is depending on .Net 4.6. The `Compare` namespace comes with the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions` library. Setting the right cpu architecture and referencing .Net 4.6 (or higher) should get things working for you as you planned.

Answer (score 3):

After getting the package to work (target x86 and .Net 4.6 or higher), comparing should be as simple as this:

```
var source = new SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint("YourSourceConnectionStringHere");
var target = new SchemaCompareDatabaseEndpoint("YourTargetConnectionStringHere");
var comparison = new SchemaComparison(source, target);
var result = comparison.Compare();
var differences = result.GenerateScript("YourDatabaseNameHere");
string script = differences.Script;
```

Comment: Thank you. This will only compare schema. by the way how did you extract to a dacpac from DB. I was able to extract DB to a bacpac file, data + schema, but could find any to extract dacpac. Does you example compare data?

Comment: My example only compares the schema and will only produce (or run) the script applying the changes to synchronize the schema. I couldn't find any way to use an extension of Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx to compare the data.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 provides a data comparison option in the IDE, do you know if we can use that in the C# project anyway? do you know the DLL that we can reference to get that command? thank you in advance

Comment: I don't have VS 2017 at hand - you could try to track down the used component by procmon or something the like.

Comment: I couldn't get that working.. my differences.Script;call always return null

Comment: @ManishRawat You may want to post question of your own specific problem including your code and mention this post for reference.

Comment: I used exactly the code you mentioned in your answer post and after calling generatescript method the returned object properties always returning null.. I thought you answered it already so didn’t bothered asking another question